# Jmeter throws 403 forbidden when calling multiple threads

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

I am using jmeter to perform load testing on my dev cluster. I have used HTTP Authorization Manager  and have passed baseurl, username, password etc. Now my thread group have:

> Number of threads:100 ,
> Ramp-up period: 1 and Loop Count:1

Now for the first 50-60 calls the authorization works as expected but later it starts failing by giving error as 403. can anyone please tell me how to fix this?

[image]

I am using jmeter 5.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Is there any response data? Perhaps you are getting rate limited. I also noticed you are reading in variables from a CSV. Are you sure the data in each row is correct? If you are providing auth credentials through the CSV, an incorrect row could lead to a 403.

As a side note, JMeter 5.4.1 has a log4j vulnerability, you might want to upgrade it to the latest version.

Comment: Hi @Tyler Liu, No there is no response data. And yes I am reading variables from CSV but it is only to create body of my POST call. Credentials are coming from HTTP Authorization Manager. Data in each row seems to be alright. And thank you for pointing out, I will update the version for vulnerability.

Comment: If you're sure that the request body and headers are the same for each request, then I can't think of any other explanation besides rate limiting. Are you calling a 3rd party API with this request?

Comment: yeah request body looks ok to me because i have removed csv data set and tried calling with a particular body and still the same thing is happening so I don't think that is a problem. Maybe the authentication have a rate limit and for every post it is trying to authenticate and there it is failing. Is it any way we can cache the authentication?

Comment: I'm not sure :(  Do you have access to any server logs? I hope you find a solution soon!

Answer (score 0):

If the problem occurs under the load I can think of 2 possible reasons:

1. Your application gets overloaded and cannot properly handle the requests. Check your application logs and resources usage (CPU, RAM, etc.)
2. JMeter gets overloaded and not being able to properly send the requests. You're violating several [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) in particular:

   - you're running JMeter in GUI mode, GUI is only for tests development and debugging, when it comes to execution you should be using [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
   - you're using [Listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui), especially [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree), they don't add any value and just consuming resources
   - you're not using the [latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version), current stable release is [5.4.3](https://lists.apache.org/thread/dbg1bxywcwx5vtdwqf8ownf7ppgqjn41)

Comment: Hi @Dmitri T, 
Thank you for answering. I have followed what you suggested by moving to latest jmeter and testing it via non gui mode but still it is the same error.  :(

Comment: @RiteshSingh We are facing the same issue. My best guess is due to insufficient JVM heap memory. I observed that everything worked well till the 1st Heap Dump occurred. When I increased the heap size to 4Gigs, the number of 403's reduced but it still occured. However, when I run it on Blazemeter, I don't have any option to play with JVM and 50% of my load testing end up with 403 error